# Python dictionary extension

Tags: python, dictionary

To whom it may concern,

I have the following code:

```
dict1 = {'num_wings': [1, 0], 'num_legs': [4,8]}
dict2 = {'num_wings': [3, 5], 'num_legs': [4,8]}
dict3 = {'num_wings': [6, 1], 'num_legs': [4,8]}
dict_list = [dict1,dict2,dict3]
```

and I am trying to get the following result:

```
dict_gen = {'num_wings':[1,0,3,5,6,1],'num_legs':[4,8,4,8,4,8]} 
dict_gen
```

Could someone help me bridge my gap? I would appreciate any thoughts that you may have.

-Many thanks

Comment: What have you tried and how does it fail?

Comment: Here is a tip: You are trying to **concatenate** the lists. Now try to write a for loop over the values of the dict such that you can concatenate the lists. This is the most naive approach, but it should suit you just fine.

Comment: "to whom it may concern" is not a good intro because it is rather vague and not clear who it is addressing. I would get rid of extra fluff in the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through `dict_list`, and concatenate each dictionary element to the corresponding element of `dict_gen`.

```
dict_gen = {'num_wings':[],'num_legs':[]} 
for d in dict_list:
    dict_gen['num_wings'] += d['num_wings']
    dict_gen['num_legs'] += d['num_legs']
```

If you want a more general solution that doesn't require you to hard-code the dictionary keys, you can use `defaultdict` to create the elements as needed.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_gen = defaultdict(list)
for d in dict_list:
    for k, v in d.items():
        dict_gen[k] += v
```